# is there an equivalent if statement in java as this python one?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, boolean

I usually code python, but decided to try to learn a new language (Java). I am a complete beginner with around 2 hours of experience. In python, we can use "or" so that if one condition is satisfied it executes the block of code.EG:

```py
if x>y or 10<12:
  print("one of these is true")
```

is there an equivalent for this in java ?

Comment: Since you are beginner, did you try reading tutorials, java documents etc? This would be basic and covered in basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
if( x > y || 10 < 12) { 
System.out.println("one of these is true"); 
}
```

should do the thing.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for you.

```
if (x>y || 10<12) {
 print("one of these is true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent if-statement would be

```
if (x > y || 10 < 12) {
    ....
}
```

Alternatively you can just skip that, since `10 < 12` will always evaluate to true.